# How can I autocomplete Softimage code from PyCharm?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I am following the [Conquering the code in Softimage XSI tutorials](https://codingforxsi.wordpress.com/) for writing Python plugins for Softimage (on Windows).

I'd like to edit code in my preferred editor (PyCharm) but I've noticed that PyCharm is unable to introspect Softimage classes/modules and provide autocompletion. Is there any way to make PyCharm aware of the Softimage internals?

Comment: Is the softimage SDK part of your `PYTHONPATH`?.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid good idea, now to find out what the path to the SDK is :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the project interpreter to `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Softimage\Application\python\python.exe` did the trick (thanks @BurhanKhalid for asking about the PYTHONPATH). All the Softimage-based completions now work.

**Additional libraries**

In my case I needed additional Python libraries as well. This can be achieved in two ways:

1. *Create a virtualenv.* Using PyCharm, create a virtualenv based on the Softimage interpreter. Add the additional libraries to the virtualenv.
2. *Clone the interpreter.* Copy `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Softimage\Application\python\` to `C:\Python26SoftimageClone\`. Using PyCharm, add package management to the cloned interpreter (File | Settings.... | Project | Project interpreter | "Install packaging tools"). Add libraries via the PyCharm interface.

**Quirky libraries for Windows**

I went with option 2 because of additional complications arising out of two libraries I needed: PyQt4 and MySQLdb (aka MySQL-python). I installed them as follows:

- Used an old exe installer of the Python 2.6 build of PyQt4. (I don't know of an online source.) When prompted for an interpreter path, used the path of the cloned interpreter.
- Downloaded a wheel installer of the Python 2.6 build of MySQLdb. [(Downloaded from Christoph Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages.)](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) Installed it with the cloned interpreter's pip as follows:

`C:\>cd\Python26SoftimageClone\Scripts
C:\Python26SoftimageClone\Scripts>pip install C:\Users\name\Downloads\MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp26-none-win_amd64.whl`

I now have autocompletion for Softimage builtins, PyQt4 and MySQLdb.